# SQL invalid identifier code

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to make 3 tables 2 with foreign keys to the rest. I keep getting error codes when I try to insert data into the table so I figured I would isolate the create tables and attempt to fix there. The code is as follows:

```
-- Spool the execution output to a text file.  This spooled file serves as logs.
spool on
spool hw2.lst
set echo on


-- All the DROP TABLE in the beginning.

DROP TABLE movie CASCADE CONSTRAINTS;
DROP TABLE companies CASCADE CONSTRAINTS;
DROP TABLE producer CASCADE CONSTRAINTS;

-- Creates Table CUSTOMER.

CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER (
cust_ID NUMBER(10),
last_name VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
first_name VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
MI VARCHAR2(1) NOT NULL,
street VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,
city VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,
state VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,
zip_code VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT customer_pk PRIMARY KEY(cust_ID));

-- Creates Table SALE_VEHICLE.

CREATE TABLE SALE_VEHICLE (
VIN NUMBER(20),
trade_ID NUMBER(10),
make VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,
model VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,
type VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,
where_frome VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,
wholesale_cost NUMBER(8,2)NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT producer_pk PRIMARY KEY(VIN));


-- Creates Table SALE.

CREATE TABLE SALE (
sale_ID NUMBER(6),
cust_ID NUMBER(10),
salesperson_ID NUMBER(10),
VIN NUMBER(20),
date DATE NOT NULL,
vehicle_status VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
milage VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
gross_sale_price NUMBER(8,2)NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT sale_pk PRIMARY KEY(sale_ID))
CONSTRAINT customers_fk2 FOREIGN KEY(cust_ID) REFERENCES CUSTOMER(cust_ID))
CONSTRAINT VIN_fk FOREIGN KEY(VIN) REFERENCES SALE_VEHICLE(VIN));

-- spool off command to turn off the spool with it you may not get the all the content spooled.

set echo off
spool off
```

This is what is echoed after I attempt to run the sql file:

```
SQL> 
SQL> 
SQL> -- All the DROP TABLE in the beginning.
SQL> 
SQL> DROP TABLE movie CASCADE CONSTRAINTS;
DROP TABLE movie CASCADE CONSTRAINTS
           *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist 


SQL> DROP TABLE companies CASCADE CONSTRAINTS;
DROP TABLE companies CASCADE CONSTRAINTS
           *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist 


SQL> DROP TABLE producer CASCADE CONSTRAINTS;
DROP TABLE producer CASCADE CONSTRAINTS
           *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist 


SQL> 
SQL> -- Creates Table CUSTOMER.
SQL> 
SQL> CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER (
  2  cust_ID NUMBER(10),
  3  last_name VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
  4  first_name VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
  5  MI VARCHAR2(1) NOT NULL,
  6  street VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,
  7  city VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,
  8  state VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,
  9  zip_code VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
 10  CONSTRAINT customer_pk PRIMARY KEY(cust_ID));
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER (
             *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object 


SQL> 
SQL> -- Creates Table SALE_VEHICLE.
SQL> 
SQL> CREATE TABLE SALE_VEHICLE (
  2  VIN NUMBER(20),
  3  trade_ID NUMBER(10),
  4  make VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,
  5  model VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,
  6  type VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,
  7  where_frome VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,
  8  wholesale_cost NUMBER(8,2)NOT NULL,
  9  CONSTRAINT producer_pk PRIMARY KEY(VIN));
CREATE TABLE SALE_VEHICLE (
             *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object 


SQL> 
SQL> 
SQL> -- Creates Table SALE.
SQL> 
SQL> CREATE TABLE SALE (
  2  sale_ID NUMBER(6),
  3  cust_ID NUMBER(10),
  4  salesperson_ID NUMBER(10),
  5  VIN NUMBER(20),
  6  date DATE NOT NULL,
  7  vehicle_status VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
  8  milage VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
  9  gross_sale_price NUMBER(8,2)NOT NULL,
 10  CONSTRAINT sale_pk PRIMARY KEY(sale_ID))
 11  CONSTRAINT customers_fk2 FOREIGN KEY(cust_ID) REFERENCES CUSTOMER(cust_ID))
 12  CONSTRAINT VIN_fk FOREIGN KEY(VIN) REFERENCES SALE_VEHICLE(VIN));
date DATE NOT NULL,
*
ERROR at line 6:
ORA-00904: : invalid identifier 


SQL> 
SQL> -- spool off command to turn off the spool with it you may not get the all the content spooled.
SQL> 
SQL> set echo off
```

Any help would be great thanks.

Comment: You drop tables Movies, Companies, Producer; you create tables Customer, Sale_Vehicle, Sale — and get told that Customer already exists.  Why drop tables you aren't creating, and why not drop tables you are creating?  And using a keyword `date` for a column name doesn't fly well.  You need to mark it as a 'delimited identifier' (enclose in double quotes, or in a platform specific alternative such as square brackets), or use a different name.

Comment: Have you set your DB Case Insensitive? Your create commands have table names in uppercase while your DROP in lowercase. Not sure this is your issue, but it would worth trying.

Comment: Well in my class I am taking the professor says it is a good habit to get into dropping tables so that every time you run the script you won't get the error message table already exist.

Comment: Yes; it is a good idea to drop the tables you're about to create.  It is an appalling idea to drop unrelated tables.  You're abusing the system two different ways at once — congratulations on your inventiveness.

Comment: Please remember to add the tag for the specific DBMS you are using — answers tend to vary between different DBMS, even though SQL is (nominally) standardized.

Comment: Ok yeah I messed up that part with dropping the correct tables. Thanks. Know the only error I am getting is the line in the SALES table where I create the date

Comment: Sorry about that I am using SQL Plus

Comment: I think I am using the wrong code for the date even though in the first SQL class I took it was the same one

Comment: Ok fixed the date error, it was the fact I was using date as the variable and with DATE. Now I am getting an error at the cust_ID foreign key code in the SALES table

Comment: says missing or invalid option

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out here is the answer:

```
-- Spool the execution output to a text file.  This spooled file serves as logs.
spool on
spool hw2.lst
set echo on


-- All the DROP TABLE in the beginning.

DROP TABLE CUSTOMER CASCADE CONSTRAINTS;
DROP TABLE SALE_VEHICLE CASCADE CONSTRAINTS;
DROP TABLE SALE CASCADE CONSTRAINTS;

-- Creates Table CUSTOMER.

CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER (
cust_ID NUMBER(10),
last_name VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
first_name VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
MI VARCHAR2(1) NOT NULL,
street VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,
city VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,
state VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,
zip_code VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT customer_pk PRIMARY KEY(cust_ID));

-- Creates Table SALE_VEHICLE.

CREATE TABLE SALE_VEHICLE (
VIN NUMBER(20),
trade_ID NUMBER(10),
make VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,
model VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,
type VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,
where_frome VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,
wholesale_cost NUMBER(8,2)NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT producer_pk PRIMARY KEY(VIN));


-- Creates Table SALE.

CREATE TABLE SALE (
sale_ID NUMBER(6),
cust_ID NUMBER(10),
salesperson_ID NUMBER(10),
VIN NUMBER(20),
date_received DATE NOT NULL,
vehicle_status VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
milage VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
gross_sale_price NUMBER(8,2)NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT sale_pk PRIMARY KEY(sale_ID),
CONSTRAINT customers_fk2 FOREIGN KEY(cust_ID) REFERENCES CUSTOMER(cust_ID),
CONSTRAINT VIN_fk FOREIGN KEY(VIN) REFERENCES SALE_VEHICLE(VIN));

-- spool off command to turn off the spool with it you may not get the all the content spooled.

set echo off
spool off
```

Comment: Brilliant! Now you may want to remove the entire thread - you didn't expose any "common issue" that others would be likely to learn anything from. Thank you!